# How can I install Calabash-android for Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, calabash, calabash-ios, calabash-android

I am new to Calabash and recently switched from Windows to Ubuntu. Can anyone give me detailed steps on how to install Calabash-android for Ubuntu 14.04?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you search for the solution?

On the GitHub page they have 3 steps https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/wiki/Ubuntu-Setup

> Steps to setup calabash-android on Ubuntu.
>   1. Install Oracle JDK 7 and add it to your path.
>   2. Install Ruby 1.9.3 using rvm
>
> 3. gem install calabash-android

Also this post might help you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24591513/1165581 by [Arunjyothis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3806809/arunjyothis)

Answer (score 0):

U also will need Android SDK , after you install you have to set

`export ANDROID_HOME=path/to/sdk`

also i suggest you to install virtualbox + genymotion to emulate the Mobile Phone